# In-app billing validation

Tags: java, android, security

I'm trying to add an in-app subscription to my app and if I understand Google's guidelines correctly, the proper way to validate in-app purchases is as follows:

1. My app queries active subscriptions from Google's billing API
2. My app sends active subscription details to my server
3. My server sends the details to Google, which responds with whether they are valid
4. My server responds back to my app with whether the details are valid
5. My app now knows whether the user is legitimately subscribed

I'm not very familiar with network security, but this process is apparently secure because the alternative is to validate the subscription solely in the app which attackers can reverse engineer and figure out the logic behind it. But I fail to see how receiving a yes/no response from my server is better. Couldn't attackers spoof my server's response if they wanted? Or at least modify the code where the yes/no response is interpreted?

Comment: The short answer is you are right, they can. Any functionality in a mobile app is available to its user, regardless of any protection in the app. It may not be so straightforward, but ultimately that's the case.